# What is the css/xpath for the hidden span price tag (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I've been trying to figure out how to get the price out of this for a while. Could someone please explain to me with an example of how to extract data from this site? It can be requests, beautiful soup, scrapy, or selenium. I would just like to see a way to get to these hidden elements.

I am using python 3.8 macOS.
[image]

url:

https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaJgCiAEBmAExuAEHyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAKJn_76BcACAdICJDU3YTg4ZDhiLTRkZmUtNGNlYi1hZGYxLWFiNjNiY2NjOGNhM9gCBOACAQ&sid=c3b17be33020b4a83d961a9fc14cf31d&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaJgCiAEBmAExuAEHyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAKJn_76BcACAdICJDU3YTg4ZDhiLTRkZmUtNGNlYi1hZGYxLWFiNjNiY2NjOGNhM9gCBOACAQ%3Bsid%3Dc3b17be33020b4a83d961a9fc14cf31d%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Maribor&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Maribor&ssne_untouched=Maribor&dest_id=-88556&dest_type=city&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=16&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=9&checkout_monthday=18&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I state that the Booking.com site expressly violates scraping.
If you want this script with selenium find the prices of each hotel on the page. If you need other elements just let me know.

EDIT: this script find determinate prices you have to change the class for another prices.

Sorry for the English I'm an an Italian Student :-)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('CHROMEDRIVER PATH')

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaJgCiAEBmAExuAEHyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAKJn_76BcACAdICJDU3YTg4ZDhiLTRkZmUtNGNlYi1hZGYxLWFiNjNiY2NjOGNhM9gCBOACAQ&sid=c3b17be33020b4a83d961a9fc14cf31d&sb=1&sb_lp=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1DCAEoggI46AdIM1gEaJgCiAEBmAExuAEHyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAKJn_76BcACAdICJDU3YTg4ZDhiLTRkZmUtNGNlYi1hZGYxLWFiNjNiY2NjOGNhM9gCBOACAQ%3Bsid%3Dc3b17be33020b4a83d961a9fc14cf31d%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=Maribor&is_ski_area=0&ssne=Maribor&ssne_untouched=Maribor&dest_id=-88556&dest_type=city&checkin_year=2020&checkin_month=9&checkin_monthday=16&checkout_year=2020&checkout_month=9&checkout_monthday=18&group_adults=2&group_children=0&no_rooms=1&b_h4u_keep_filters=&from_sf=1')

prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='bui-u-sr-only']")

for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```